# Apache Tiles Integration : org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException

Tags: java, jsp, tiles, apache-tiles

I'm trying simple `Apache Tiles Integration`. And here are my classes.

**WEB-INF/tiles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="template"
                template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/template.jsp" />
    <definition name="*" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name="body"
                       value="/WEB-INF/jsp/{1}.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

**com.dilini.tiles.config.AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dilini.tiles.controller"})
public class AppConfig {
    // declare Tiles configuration file

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        final String[] definitions = {"/WEB-INF/tiles.xml"};
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(definitions);
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }
// declare Tiles as a view resolver

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

**com.dilini.tiles.controller.TileController**

```
@Controller
public class TileController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String returnHome(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**jsp/templates/template.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles"
           uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Spring Cookbook</h1>
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And finally 
**jsp/home.jsp**

```
<body>
        <h1>Hello Home!</h1>
</body>
```

The problem is when I try to run the application by **http://localhost:8080/tiles/** I'm getting 500 error saying

```
Exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: XML error reading definitions.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactoryException: XML error reading definitions.
    org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:328)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromResource(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:150)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:234)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:225)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:225)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:203)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:192)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:68)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.checkAndloadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:174)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:131)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:105)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:49)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.java:89)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.getDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:286)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.isValidDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:273)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.isRenderable(DefinitionRenderer.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.checkResource(TilesView.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1283)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1224)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 19; Document is invalid: no grammar found.
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:228)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3138)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:880)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1887)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.read(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:325)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromResource(BaseLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:150)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:234)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:225)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadRawDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:225)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitionsFromResources(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:203)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:192)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.loadDefinitions(ResolvingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:68)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.checkAndloadDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:174)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinitions(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:131)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:105)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.dao.CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.getDefinition(CachingLocaleUrlDefinitionDAO.java:49)
    org.apache.tiles.definition.UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.getDefinition(UnresolvingLocaleDefinitionsFactory.java:89)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.getDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:286)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.isValidDefinition(BasicTilesContainer.java:273)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.isRenderable(DefinitionRenderer.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.checkResource(TilesView.java:116)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1283)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1224)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I think the error is in tiles.xml file. But I have no idea what it is?

Please help me to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: please help me thanks